# Dynamically Created Input Not Submitted With Request

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

When submitting a form, my last table row of inputs is not getting submitted with the request and I can't figure out why. The last row is generated by a JavaScript function, but there is no difference that I can see out side of the value. The value in the other ones is loaded with the page.

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input name="companyid1" id="companyid1" size="5" value="1001"></td>
    <td><input name="files1" id="files1" size="80" value="something.txt"></td>
    <td><input name="check_dont_delete1" id="check_dont_delete1" type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input name="companyid2" id="companyid2" size="5" value="1001"></td>
    <td><input name="files2" id="files2" size="80" value="junk.txt"></td>
    <td><input name="check_dont_delete2" id="check_dont_delete2" type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td><input name="companyid3" id="companyid3" size="5"></td>
    <td><input name="files3" id="files3" size="80"></td>
    <td><input name="check_dont_delete3" id="check_dont_delete3" type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
```

In the Chrome Developers Tools Network Tab, I'm looking at the form data  and it doesn't find it.

It will submit all the previous ones, but not the one that was dynamically added.

Here is my form data from a request with this info:

**Form Data:**

companyid1:1001

files1:something.txt

companyid2:1001

files2:junk.txt

**JavaScript Function**:

```
function addRowToTable() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById('destinations');
    var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;

    // if there's no header row in the table, then iteration = lastRow + 1
    var iteration = lastRow;
    var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

    // left cell
    var cellLeft = row.insertCell(0);
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(iteration);
    cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);

    // right cell
    var cellRight = row.insertCell(1);
    var el = document.createElement('input');
    el.name = 'companyid' + iteration;
    el.id = 'companyid' + iteration;
    el.size = 5;
    cellRight.appendChild(el);

    // select cell
    var cellRightSel = row.insertCell(2);
    var sel = document.createElement('input');
    sel.name = 'files' + iteration;
    sel.id = 'files' + iteration;
    sel.size = 80;

    cellRightSel.appendChild(sel);


    // select cell
    var cellRightcheck = row.insertCell(3);
    var selc = document.createElement('input'); 
    selc.name = 'check_dont_delete' + iteration;
    selc.id = 'check_dont_delete' + iteration;
    selc.type = 'checkbox';

    cellRightcheck.appendChild(selc);
}
```

**Form & Submit:**

```
<form method="post" class="form" action="new_edit.php?id=1" name="add_edit" id="update__form">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-bl" name="update">Update</button
```

**Note**: This is legacy code I'm trying to debug for a new project I joined.

Comment: "*The last row is generated by a JavaScript function*'. Can you please add the JavaScript code generating the row? It's my guess that it's outside of the scope.

Comment: The mechanic used to submit the form could be helpful as well

Comment: @ObsidianAge - JavaScript function added.

Comment: @Frederik.L added the form & submit button

Comment: Can you post the entire thing? Maybe use a snippet / jsfiddle?

Comment: @motanelu Sorry - I can't post the whole thing. There is a lot of PHP generating misc stuff.

Comment: Does the table have a header? Is the table within the form?

Comment: It's fixed. It was out of scope. The PHP was causing invalid HTML markup so the form tag was closing earlier than expected.